# How to specify updatePasswordUrl like loginFormUrl = '/saml/login' in a project using Spring Security SAML plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using [Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) in my project and its working fine. I have following in my SamlSecurityConfig.groovy file

```
loginFormUrl = '/saml/login'
```

so when I go to /saml/login then it redirects me to my IDP's login page and after login in IDP I get redirected to my app.
Now I want to know that is there any configuration in Spring Security SAML where I can specify a update password url and by going to that url my app should redirect to my IDP's forget password/update password page and after resetting password on IDP I should get redirected to my app's login page.

Can anyone please help?

Following is my **SamlSecurityConfig.groovy** file

```
security {
    saml {
        userAttributeMappings = ['userName': 'userName']
        userGroupToRoleMapping = [:]
        active = true
        afterLoginUrl = '/'
        afterLogoutUrl = '/'
        loginFormUrl = '/saml/login'
        userGroupAttribute = "memberOf"
        responseSkew = 10000
        idpSelectionPath = '/'
        autoCreate {
            active =  true
            key = 'username'
            assignAuthorities = true
        }
        metadata {
            defaultIdp = 'http://idp.ssocircle.com'
            url = '/saml/metadata'
            //default idp info
            idp{
                file = 'security/idp.xml'
                alias = 'http://idp.ssocircle.com'
            }
            sp {
                file = 'security/sp.xml'
                alias = 'myapp'
                defaults{
                    local = true
                    alias = 'myapp'
                    signingKey = 'ping'
                    encryptionKey = 'ping'
                    tlsKey = 'ping'
                    requireArtifactResolveSigned = false
                    requireLogoutRequestSigned = false
                    requireLogoutResponseSigned = false
                    idpDiscoveryEnabled = true
                }
            }
        }
        keyManager {
            storeFile = 'classpath:security/keystore.jks'
            storePass = 'nalle123'
            passwords = [ ping: 'ping123' ]
            defaultKey = 'ping'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Authentication itself and so password change is out of scope from SAMLv2 spec point of view, so it would not really be covered by an SAMLv2 SP implementation like Spring Security SAML extension. Actually the SP does not even know where or how authentication takes place at the IdP side.

--> Your app, acting as the SP, should not bother with this.